# problems authenticating after updating asp.net mvc app with azure ad

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I created an asp.net **mvc app (not core)** using the **azure ad** integration.
Generally speaking works fine, but I'm facing some problems in production, especially after a server update.
Often, after the appplication has been updated and restarted, clients go in an infinite loop after authentication and returning to the calling app, and after a while the problem disappear.
How can I solve this? this is a very odd problem, especially because we are not able to predict when the app restart to work properly.

Comment: Did you check if all your URI configurations are correct ?

Comment: the application works properly for hours in production and in development, the problem happens sometimes in production and seems after an update or process recycling